# dotnet command wont create files

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

I am trying to make a new `.NET` console project as shown in 
[this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio-code).

```
dotnet new console
```

But nothing happens. I expect the `Program.cs` and `HelloWorld.csproj` files to be created, but this isn't the case and I have no clue why. For those wondering, my environment consists of the following

- Windows Server 2012 R2
- Visual Studio Code
- `.NET` Core SDK 2.0.3

**UPDATE**

This is all ran within `virtualbox` + `vagrant` + `Windows Remote Desktop` on OSX High Sierra. To reproduce this issue, simply run `vagrant up` alongside this `Vagrantfile`

```ruby
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "opentable/win-2012r2-standard-amd64-nocm"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", host: 3389, guest: 3389

  config.vm.communicator = "winrm"
end
```

Then use `Microsoft Remote Desktop` to use the VM. Do this by clicking `New` and entering in the following info

```
PC name : 127.0.0.1:3389
User name : vagrant
Password : vagrant
```

When logged in to the Windows VM, simply download the `.NET SDK` and start trying `dotnet` commands in `powershell`. If you're like me, you'll notice that nothing happens, which sucks.

I'm currently downloading a trial version of `WindowsServer2012-R2` to see if there are any differences between that image and the image I'm currently using (which is [hosted by vagrant](https://app.vagrantup.com/opentable/boxes/win-2012r2-standard-amd64-nocm)).

Comment: Is anything happen at all?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the correct directory? It works for me ( WIndows 10 though)

Comment: Just tested in on my Windows Server 2012R2 and it worked like a charm.

Comment: @jAC, nope. Within the vscode terminal, I get no stdout or stderr string. Even when inspecting `tree` in powershell, I don't notice any new files.

Comment: @jAC Hmm, I'll try removing and reinstalling vscode and the .NET SDK. I am running this within a vagrant+virtualbox+Microsoft Remote Desktop within OSX. So idk if the VM is having issues with it.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, Quite Certain.

Comment: Does `dotnet new --help` output anything? Otherwise, try `powershell -command get-command dotnet` to verify `dotnet` is resolving to the right command.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, `powershell -command get-command dotnet` gives a `CommandType`, `Name`, `ModuleName` tuple of `Application`, `dotnet.exe`, `<empty string>`. The `dotnet new --help` doesn't output anything.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I ended up installing a fresh image of WindowsServer2012 and the `dotnet` command now works fine. It seems as though the image I was previously using was flawed in its own way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pre-configured [Windows Server Image](https://app.vagrantup.com/opentable/boxes/win-2012r2-standard-amd64-nocm) was flawed for the task. After I provisioned a fresh [Windows Server 2012 R2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2012-r2) Image by hand, I was able to run the `dotnet` commands without fail.